# Firebase data structure for a twitter conversation threads clone like

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, twitter

I want to give the possibility for my users to talk with each other like in this example:

[image: example]

But I don't know how do I must set my database to recreate this type of conversation.

I think my database should look like that, but this is not working.

```json
{
  "Users": {
    "user1":"info",
    "user2":"info",
    "user3":"info",
    "user4":"info"
  },
  "Tweet": {
    "Tweet1":"info",
    "Tweet2":"info",
    "Tweet3":"info"
  }

  "Converation": {
    "conversation1": {
      "Tweet1":"Tweet1-Id",
      "Tweet2":"Tweet2-Id",

    }
  }
}
```

With this structure everytimes one of the user answer a comment made in one conversation I need to create another conversation-child ( it would be conversation2 in this exemple ) and it must do that over and over

```json
{
  "Converation": {
    "conversation1": {
      "Tweet1":"Tweet1-Id",
      "Tweet2":"Tweet2-Id",

    }
 "conversation2": {
      "conversation1":"info",
      "Tweet2":"Tweet2-Id",

    }
  }
}
```

The thing is that I dont know how to structure my database for making conversational threads like twitter does and I would like to do that.

Do you have  any exemple of what im trying to achieve using firebase and java ?

Comment: "is not woking" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexMamo he/she is asking data structures or db schema for such type of dynamic nesting. In this case replies of replies and so on.

Comment: @AnkitMishra We are usually structuring the database according to the queries that we want to perform. @ Darky What are those queries? What doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo the structure Im using ( the one I showed as exemple  )  doesnt load the tweets   , and I cant figure how I must do it

Comment: "doesnt load the tweets" doesn't either provide enough information so we can help. Please take a moment and read, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AlexMamo ok I understand let me just some minutes to edit my question corretly

Comment: @AlexMamo I edited my question I hope it is more clear what the problem is ,  if it is not jut say it  , I will try to explay more in details

Comment: @AnkitMishra yes is that what im asking for  !

Comment: You say *The thing is that I don't know how to structure my database for making conversational threads*, but you already tried something. What's wrong with the shared attempt?